# What measures does google cloud take to protect the instances from IP spoofing?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running my server on `google app engine` and i have all of my services (e.g MongoDB, Redis, Elasticsearch) are deployed on compute engine. Now i wanted to connect my compute engine instances from App engine only that's why i deleted all of my firewall rules of my compute engines which were connecting them from external ip's, now only the instances that are within the internal network of my google cloud project can connect to themselves, now i am just wondering about **IP spoofing** that as nobody from outside my internal network can connect to my instances now can they fake their ip by telling my firewall that their ip is the ip which any of my instance is having because if that can happen then my whole security will be breached.

Now one question does google cloud project's firewall implement any measures to secure our instances from IP Spoofing or we have to setup something in order to avoid that.

If any of you have any idea about this please enlighten me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear which spoofing scenario you are concerned about. These two come to mind:

- External party spoofing packets for your **internal network**, ie. the 10.0.0.0/8 range. This is not possible as packets inside your network can only come from VMs and VPNs in that private network.
- Spoofing packets from other Google / GCE IP ranges; eg. the ones used for external addresses: This should be caught by Google's network ACLs.

I would however not recommend to authenticate based on IP address. For example, if you are communicating over external IP addresses between GCE/GAE entities, it's easy to be too broad, also allowing other GCE/GAE customers. Even if you only whitelist single IP addresses there is a risk that over time, your setup becomes more complex. Imagine for example, if an employee deletes a GCE instance without also removing the IP from the whitelist. In that case, the IP would be released and available to other GCE customers who could then access your service.

Therefore, it's usually safer to use an application level authentication mechanism such as SSL client certificates.

Comment: For point one can any `external hacker fake his/her Ip and tell my firewall that he/she is internal` and can access my compute engines or not ?? Also For point two same question as above ??

Comment: ALso can you please tell me how can i add SSl client certificates in connection between `App Engine and Compute Engine`.